# Toggle css-pseudo element on wordpress

Tags: javascript, css

I am struggling with creating a mobile drop down menu on wordpress. I would like to make a 180° rotation of the arrow, "on click".

The problem is that I'm on wordpress, and I can't change my html code. So I added a pseudo-element :after in the css to get an arrow.

I would like to know how to select it ( in css or js ) to create and call this rotation.

Thanks a lot for your help, here is the snippet:

```css
.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu .menu-item-object-page a {
  margin: 0 0 0 1rem;
}

.mobile-menu .sub-menu {
  display: inherit;
  transition: height 0.2s;
  opacity: 0;
  position:relative;
  height:0;
  padding-top:0;
  padding-bottom:0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.mobile-menu li:hover .sub-menu  {
  opacity: 1;
}
.mobile-menu li:hover .sub-menu li {
  height:auto;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}
.mobile-menu .sub-menu li {
  height:0;
  padding-top:0;
  padding-bottom:0;
}
.menu-item-has-children:hover .sub-menu {
  /*display: block;*/
  visibility: visible;
  transform: translateY(0px);
}

.mobile-menu .sub-menu li:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
 }

.mobile-menu .menu-item-has-children > a::after {
  content: "\276F";
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.mobile-menu .menu-item-has-children a {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


.menu-item-has-children {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 240px;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 17px 20px 20px 20px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgb(115 132 167 / 40%);
  border-radius: 0px 0px 20px 20px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  
}

.sub-menu li {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 15px 5px 15px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile-menu">
<ul class="menu">
<li class="menu-item-has-children">
<a aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" rel="external">MENU A</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page ">1</li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page ">2</li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page ">3</li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page ">4</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu .menu-item-object-page a {
  margin: 0 0 0 1rem;
}

.mobile-menu .sub-menu {
  display: inherit;
  transition: height 0.2s;
  opacity: 0;
  position:relative;
  height:0;
  padding-top:0;
  padding-bottom:0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.mobile-menu li:hover .sub-menu  {
  opacity: 1;
}
.mobile-menu li:hover .sub-menu li {
  height:auto;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}
.mobile-menu .sub-menu li {
  height:0;
  padding-top:0;
  padding-bottom:0;
}
.menu-item-has-children:hover .sub-menu {
  /*display: block;*/
  visibility: visible;
  transform: translateY(0px);
}

.mobile-menu .sub-menu li:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
 }

.mobile-menu .menu-item-has-children > a::after {
  content: "\276F";
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  /* Add transition timing to match dropdown */
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

/* New: Add hover and/or focus CSS */
.mobile-menu .menu-item-has-children:hover > a::after {
  transform: rotate(-90deg)
}
/* End New */

.mobile-menu .menu-item-has-children a {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


.menu-item-has-children {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 240px;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 17px 20px 20px 20px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgb(115 132 167 / 40%);
  border-radius: 0px 0px 20px 20px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  
}

.sub-menu li {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 15px 5px 15px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile-menu">
<ul class="menu">
<li class="menu-item-has-children">
<a aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" rel="external">MENU A</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page ">1</li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page ">2</li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page ">3</li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page ">4</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```